# My Dropbox shared folder is not syncing to my second computer

Tags: dropbox

I have created a shared folder, but it is not syncing to my second computer. Everything else does, but not that folder.

Answer (score 2):

On the (non-syncing) second computer, go to `Dropbox Preferences` -> `Account tab` -> `Selective Sync` and ensure the box net to that folder is checked.